# Delphi Android Solution / ARM7 with NEON marketshare?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

When developing an app for Android using Delphi I need to know the market share it supports (for a customer)

The version requirements is okay ~roughly 99% af active phones: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

But what is the marketshare of current Android telehpones in current use (or sold the last 3 or 4 years) that has ARM7+NEON?

And is there any way to e.g. run Delphi apps on Android without NEON?

Comment: I now removed the part where I ask "where" I can see marketshare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delphi currently produces applications that can only run on ARMv7 + NEON processors. There is no way around that limitation.

There is QC report for supporting processors without NEON [[Android] Add support for processors without NEON](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=118203)  and QC report for supporting Intel based Android devices [[Android] [Intel] CPU/Processor compatibility](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=121186)

There have also been some experiments that prove Delphi compiled apps can run on Intel devices via ARM emulation [Tomohiro Takahashi on Twitter: "FireMonkey app(for ARMv7) works on Intel-based ASUS ZenFone 4(Atom, Kitkat 4.4.2) "](https://plus.google.com/+DalijaPrasnikar/posts/DPBCL8c4jpJ)

Native Intel support is on the current [Delphi roadmap](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43677) scheduled for after 2014

Getting correct market shares based on CPUs is almost mission impossible, since Google does not provide CPU based statistics, like it does for Android versions, screen sizes and OpenGL versions: [Android statistics](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)

Comment: Native Intel support is on the [roadmap](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43677) for "after 2014".

Comment: I vaguely remember having read NEON was part of ARM7 specification since 2011, but for the life of me, I can not find? Anyone knows?